# unable to parse API response in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, restify

I am trying to learn EmberJS and restify. I have `get` method API with following response :

```
 {"products":[{"id":1,"name":"lappy1"},{"id":2,"name":"lappy2"}]}
```

This response I am getting in my browser's network log.

My product route is like :

```
 import Ember from 'ember';
      export default Ember.Route.extend({
          model() {
              return {
                  products :this.get('store').findAll('product')
              };
          }
      });
```

My product.hbs is :

```
<div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><b>id</b></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><b>Name</b></div>     
</div>
{{#each model.products as |product|}}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">{{product.id}}</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">{{product.name}}</div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
</div>
```

My product model is :

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name:  DS.attr('string')
});
```

There is no any error on log, but my page only shows header part i.e

```
<div class="col-md-4"><b>id</b></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><b>Name</b></div>
```

which thing I am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Chrome Ember plugin and use Chrome for debugging.

I assume you are using the RESTAdapter?

Your `Route`'s `model` hook returns an object, not a promise.  This is a little odd, I would recommend using a Hash:

```
model() {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    products: this.store.findAll('product')
  });
}
```

Alternately, you could just return the result of calling the store:

```
model() {
  return this.store.findAll('product');
}
```

But in this case, you would change your templates to just use `model` instead of `model.products`.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me why to use Ember.RSVP.hash ?

Comment: `hash` returns a promise. If you return a non-promise (plain object) from the `model` hook, Ember will not wait for resolution.  Likewise, `findAll` returns a Promise as well. Unless you have a more complicated model, I recommend the second example of `model` as shown in my answer. HTH